# Use JavaScript to retroactively treat event as though it were 'pointer-event: none'

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have multiple canvas elements layered on top of each other using absolute positioning. Each canvas has some transparent space within it. When I click on this stack of canvases, I get the pixel value where the click event happened and determine if that pixel is transparent like so:

```
var context = this.element.getContext('2d');
var rect = this.element.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = Math.round(event.clientX - rect.left);
var y = Math.round(event.clientY - rect.top);

var pixelData = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;

if (pixelData[3] === 0) {
  console.log('Transparent!')
}
```

When the pixel is transparent, I'd like to treat this layer as though it had the css property `pointer-event: none;`, which would cause the click event to pass through to the next layer.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: you might be able to hide the current canvas and call get `document.elementFromPoint` to get the one under your coords.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick! If you want to add this as an answer, I'll approve. In particular, you can disable by setting the style `pointerEvent = 'none'` and then reenabling after dispatching the new click event.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of the canvas elements, you can just click the canvas below the current canvas. Like so:

```
var canvasElements = new Array();
canvasElements[0] = canvas.element.getContext('2d');
canvasElements[1] = canvas2.element.getContext('2d');
canvasElements[2] = canvas3.element.getContext('2d');
```

Then when you run your test:

```
 var context = this.element.getContext('2d');
 var rect = this.element.getBoundingClientRect();
 var x = Math.round(event.clientX - rect.left);
 var y = Math.round(event.clientY - rect.top);

 for(var i = 0; i < canvasElements.length; i++){
    var pixelData = canvasElements[1].getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;

    if (pixelData[3] === 0) {
      console.log('Transparent!');
    } else {
      break;
      //clicked canvas i
    }
 }
```